# One liner command to get secret name and secret's token

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-dashboard

What's the one liner command to replace 2 commands like below to get the Kubernetes secret's token? Example usecase will be getting token from kubernetes-dashboard-admin's secret to login and view kubernetes-dashboard.

Command example:

```
$ kubectl describe serviceaccount default
Name:                default
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   default-token-zvxf4
Tokens:              default-token-zvxf4
Events:              <none>

$ kubectl describe secret default-token-zvxf4
Name:         default-token-zvxf4
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: default
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 809835e7-2564-439f-82f3-14762688ca80

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  7 bytes
token:      TOKENHERE
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer that I discovered was below. By using [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) to retrieve and [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to pass the secret name/output to second command. Will need to decode the encrypted token with [base64](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) at the end.

```
$ kubectl get serviceaccount default -o=jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}' | xargs kubectl get secret -ojsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode
TOKENHERE%
```

*The tailing % is not part of the token*

This should be able to work on MacOS without install additional app like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which should be able to do the same. Hope this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't need to run either command.  Kubernetes will automatically mount the credentials to `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` in a pod declared using that service account, and the various Kubernetes SDKs know to look for credentials there.  [Accessing the API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) in the Kubernetes documentation describes this setup in more detail.

[Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) describes the Pod-level setup that's possible to do, though there are reasonable defaults for these.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod # or a pod spec embedded in a Deployment &c.
spec:
  serviceAccountName: my-service-account # defaults to "default"
  automountServiceAccountToken: true     # defaults to true
```

I wouldn't try to make requests from outside the cluster as a service account.  User permissions are better suited for this use case.  As a user you could launch a Job with service-account permissions if you needed to.

Comment: I've mentioned about the use case "To access kubernetes-dashboard" which is from a user's web browser. More info https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui

Answer (score 0):

Example using `kubectl describe` instead of `kubectl get` and adding the namespace definition:

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system describe sa default | grep 'Mountable secrets' | awk '{ print $3 }') | grep 'token:' | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming only one secret exists, we can use `jq` JSON [parser/processor](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to get this secret's data and then use `base64 -d` to decode it (you can do it in 1 line, but it's more self-commenting when secret name is extracted separately):

```
$ SECRET_NAME=$(kubectl get secret -o name | head -1)

$ kubectl get -o name $SECRET_NAME | xargs kubectl get -o=json | jq -r ".data[]" | base64 -d
```